# Creating a row of contents to swipe through (Xcode or Xamarin)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xamarin

I would like to create something like this (screenshot of duolingo app) in my app where I have contents in a row, and i swipe through the contents. When I stop swiping, the centermost view will snap to the center. Any ideas of how I can implement this?

[image]

Comment: Take a look at UIPageView, UICollectionView, and/or UIScroller.

Comment: could you solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a UICollectionView. There is also an excellent third party library called iCarousel that provides lots of different ways to display animated collections of items.